# Inefficient comparisons of custom data type C++

Tags: c++, efficiency, memory-management

I've got some code that I need to squeeze every bit of both time and space out of. I'm looking for a better solution to the following problem.

For reasons outside of the scope of this question, I wrote a non-native data type `Z2` that effectively wraps an array of three `int8_t`s and defines some operations over them. Most of my time spent in my code is performing comparisons on these `Z2`s (standard `<`,`==`,`>`), so I need to make these as efficient as possible. I don't care about the ordering, just that it exists. The rule for `<` is presently as follows:

```
bool Z2::operator<(const Z2 &other) const
{
    if(val[0]!=other[0]) return val[0] < other[0];
    if(val[1]!=other[1]) return val[1] < other[1];
    return val[2] < other[2];
}
```

I ran some tests and, when the `Z2` is initialized to `val[0]=i` and `other[0]=j` and $ i\neq j $, this comparison takes twice as long as `i<j`, independently of how many bits are in `i,j`. Potentially this is because of the double comparison or maybe some branching  the compiler is doing.

Now, since I don't care about the way in which this comparison is done, just that it correctly discerns equality and provides an ordering, my first thought is to store `val[0]` and `val[1]` as the high/low bits of a short integer (or something) and just use the standard comparators, dropping mine entirely. Is there another solution that would yield the same result while still preserving the distinctness of at least `val[0],val[1]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not this, which avoids the inequality comparison before the less-than altogether:

```
bool Z2::operator<(const Z2 &other) const
{
    if(val[0]<other[0]) 
      return true;
    if(val[0]==other[0])
    {
       if(val[1]<other[1])
         return true;
       if(val[1]==other[1]) 
         if (val[2]<other[2])) 
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I should add that this is exactly [`std::lexicographical_compare`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lexicographical_compare#:%7E:text=Lexicographical%20comparison%20is%20an%20operation,lexicographically%20less%20than%20the%20other.). It is not necessary to re-invent the wheel -- you should assume that the implementors of the standard library have done so efficiently.

Comment: Thanks, this helped and is a bit faster than my implementation. As a side note, the standard library's implementation is about 50% slower than the raw code.

Comment: Its funny because in my testing, OP's original function was a little faster than this, and both are faster than lexicographical_compare.

Comment: @CharlieS I don't know what's going on with lexicographical_compare and why it's (substantially) slower. My guess is that lexicographical_compare has some built-in error handling or something that adds a check of some sort. Do you have code optimization on? That could make a difference between Wolfgang's and my original code.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfgang's answer is probably the best one, because its almost guaranteed to not screw up in unpredictable ways, and the intent couldn't be more clear. That said...

If the 8 bit integers are unsigned, then yes, you can concatenate them into a padded 32 bit unsigned integer and compare them. Done. Superfast. But since you specified signed 8 bit integers, its slightly more complicated. The sign bits of the middle and last integers screw up the comparison, since they will be interpreted as part of the mantissa, which is not what you want.

One way of dealing with this is to map the signed integers to the unsigned such that their order is preserved. For example, we want 127->255 and -128->0, and 0->128. In this way, we can use the existing mechanisms to compare the unsigned values. Luckily, unsigned integers do not overflow, and we can just add 128.

EDIT: It turns out that adding 128 is a matter of flipping the most significant bit, which can be done with a bit twiddling trick. Also, make sure that your system is little endian, or those code won't work (reverse the order of `tmp`). For that matter, if you can store `val` such that it matches the endianness of the system, then you can do the assignment with one memcpy call.

Edit: After benchmarking on an actual computer, it seems like simple assignment is the way to go. On this machine, its about 50% faster than the "safe" comparison.

https://godbolt.org/z/4nKxYc5TM

````
struct Z2 {

  inline uint32_t as_uint32() const {
    const uint32_t mask = 0x80'80'80'80;
    uint8_t tmp[4];
    tmp[3] = 0;
    tmp[2] = val[0];
    tmp[1] = val[1];
    tmp[0] = val[2];
    return *reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&tmp) ^ mask;
  }

  inline bool operator<(const Z2& other) const {
    return as_uint32() < other.as_uint32();
  }

  int8_t val[3];
};
```
````

Comment: Local benchmarks are showing no perceivable difference between this and Wolfgang's approach, at least on the scale this code will be running. If there is a difference, it will end up on the order of a few hours, which won't be significant. The two methods seem to be within error of one another. That said, all of the discussion of different ways to do this has been extremely helpful to me.

Comment: I think it is platform dependent. In my testing, your original function was twice as fast as this, mine was second fastest, wolfgang's was third, and lexigraphical compare was abysmally slower than everything else. 

This has the advantage of being branch free, which is sometimes important. I think there is an opportunity to speed this up depending on how `val` is stored, but I doubt it will be meaningful enough to bother. 

If you could store your `int8_t`s as `uint8_t`s, in the right order, the situation might be quite different!

Comment: Sorry to beat a dead horse: the only way I can beat your original function is to store 4 unsigned bytes (the last being zero), in the correct order. Even then, the improvement was about 10%, probably not worth it!

Comment: It could also be compiler dependent, I suppose. It's not impossible to store the int8_t as uint8_t, but I don't see where I'd be getting much savings there, given other operations I'd need to implement. (Addition/multiplication/etc.) Also, I noticed that Wolfgang's code was a bit faster than mine before I turned on optimization, at which point they were both fairly similar.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be faster to assemble a 32-bits integer for each operands and compare them, as you initially intended. It will be equivalent to what you did "by hand".
If numbers stored in Z2 are *unsigned* bytes (which is not the case in the asked question) then it is simple, and one can use:

```
class Z2 {
   ...
   inline int32_t as_int32() const {
     return (int32_t(val[0]) << 16) | 
            (int32_t(val[1]) << 8 ) | 
             int32_t(val[2]);
   }

   inline bool operator<(const Z2& other) const {
     return as_int32() < other.as_int32();
   }
  ...
};
```

If the numbers stored in a Z2 are *signed* bytes, then this requires additional care, and the function `as_int32()` can be rewritten as follows (add 127 to `val[0]`, `val[1]` and `val[2]` in order to have positive numbers):

```
   inline int32_t as_int32() const {
     return ((int32_t(val[0])+128) << 16) | 
            ((int32_t(val[1])+128) << 8 ) | 
             (int32_t(val[2])+128);
   }
```

But then this starts to use a significant number of instructions and may be slower than the lexicographic compare in the other answer (but in the end, the only judge is benchmarking !)

But there is room for optimization, see Charlie's answer that replaces the three +128 additions with bit twiddling (nice !)

Comment: Looks like a job for a Union!

Comment: I can't spare the lost 8 bits per Z2 to build these all into a 32 bit integer. So, at most, I'd have to make val[0] and val[1] into a 16 bit integer and let val[2] hang around as its own thing. It also gets a bit annoying to do the other operations that I need with these things, but I'll experiment with that version of it.

Comment: @MichaelJarret: You could try to pack a 16 bit and an 8 bit, but that'll throw off memory alignment which might decrease perf versus using 32 bits. But if you don't have the space you don't have the space :-/

Comment: @Richard I may have spoken without thinking, since this is just performing the comparison as a 32 bit integer, not actually storing the data that way. I'll have to try this one out to see what impact this has on performance.

Comment: The 32 bit integers won't be cost anything in terms of storage, they are just temporaries used when comparing two Z2s.

Comment: @BrunoLevy yea, I'm worried about the additional operation, but it's an experimental question at this point. I have no idea what the compiler would actually do. I had to make the or into xor, though, in order to get the right behavior.

Comment: It is important to benchmark, sometimes performance results are counterintuitive, and the stopwatch is the only judge.  You had to replace 'or' with 'xor' ? That's weird, I don't understand why.

Comment: @BrunoLevy I think that the way the int32_t gets handled, it loads up all high bits with 1s whenever it's negative (so -1 = 11111111...1). So, if, say, val[2] happens to be -1, everything else gets washed away by the OR. (Similarly for other cases.) XOR doesn't necessarily preserve the same ordering, but it does preserve distinctness.

Comment: You are right ! I overlooked the fact that these are signed bytes. I updated the answer and added a reference to Charlie's answer.